# Select distinct returning indistinct rows

Tags: mysql, select, distinct

Select distinct is returning indistinct rows. Why?

I want to return distinct shops.

Here is my sql statement:

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT s.*, p.p_id
FROM 
shop s 
INNER JOIN product_shop ps on s.s_id = ps.s_id 
INNER JOIN product p ON p.p_id = ps.p_id 
WHERE 
s.country = 'new zealand'
```

Here is the result:

[image]

The product (p.p_id) needs to not be distinct, as I want to return a list of shops that have a specific product. But the Shop needs to be distinct.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what would you like it to return?

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: You could remove everything except for the first column and the last column, and the question would still make sense, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Returned rows are distinct. Distinct is applied to all returned row, not to single column. Yes, p_id is same for two rows. But if you compare all columns, there are differences between them.
If you want distinct shops - don't include in select columns from other tables, because it can cause duplicates as in your example.

Answer (score 1):

Simply don't include `p.p_id` within your selection.
I.e.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       s.*
FROM   shop s
....
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, If you will look at your entire output, you can see the `p_id`(the last column) is different for each row. Distinct applies to the entire record, not just one column.

You can either drop the `p_id` from your select, or use group by and decide which one of the `p_id` you want, perhaps max? :

```
SELECT 
     s.*, max(p.p_id)
FROM 
    shop s 
INNER JOIN product_shop ps on s.s_id = ps.s_id 
INNER JOIN product p ON p.p_id = ps.p_id 
WHERE 
    s.country = 'new zealand' 
GROUP BY s.id
```